# How to rewrite model Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media?

Tags: overrides, model

I'm re-writing catalog/product_attribute_backend_media model in my module using folllowing configuration

```
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_attribute_backend_media>Makery_S3image_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
                    </rewrite>
            </catalog>        
        </models>
    </global>
```

and my model file is like

```
<?php
class Makery_S3image_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
//snip
```

While saving product after uploading image, I'm getting error

> Invalid backend model specified:
>   catalog/product_attribute_backend_media

Comment: Any particular reason for extending abstract instead of the class you rewrite?

Comment: @LordSkeletor: Nope. I've updated to to the class being re-written `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`. Still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using following code. I'm not sure what was wrong

```
<models>
    <amazon>
        <class>Makery_Amazon_Model</class>
    </amazon>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_attribute_backend_media>Makery_Amazon_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</models>
```

and Model file

```
<?php
class Makery_Amazon_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
{
// snip
```

Comment: <amazon>
        <class>Makery_Amazon_Model</class>
    </amazon>

this is required to models